# how to close pop screen when use click outside in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular

could you please tell me `how to close pop screen when use click outside in angular 4 ?`In my demo application I have `one` button on click of button I am showing pop up screen (which is working find).I want it should close when User click outside but `not on pop up screen`  in other words it should close when user click other than pop up screen .I try to make `directive` which detect click outside or inside but it not work for me here is my code

```
import { Directive,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appOutside]',
   host: {
   '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
  }
})
export class OutsideDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  onClick(event) {
   if (!this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) // or some similar check
     alert('clicked')
     //doSomething();
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xhibr?file=src%2Fapp%2Foutside.directive.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add class to DOM nodes of popup & outside of popup (or on appOutside element). Then just checkif click event triggered on DOM part inside of popup or outside. Update your view code to:

```
<div class="hover_bkgr_fricc" *ngIf="ispopUpShow" appOutside (click)="ClickedOut($event)">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <div class="inside-popup">
        <div class="popupCloseButton" (click)="closePop()">X</div>
        <p>Add any HTML content<br />inside the popup box!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where those methods in component class can be:

```
closePop() {
    this.ispopUpShow = false;
 }

 ClickedOut(event) {
    if(event.target.className === "hover_bkgr_fricc") {
      this.ispopUpShow = false;
    } 
 }
```

[**Updated Stackblitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lvboyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

All you actually need to do is move the `appOutside` directive onto your modal, since we want to know if the click is outside of the modal. If you leave it on the `hover_bkgr_fricc` div, it will always be inside, since it's styled to take up the whole viewport

```
<div class="hover_bkgr_fricc" *ngIf="ispopUpShow" >
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <div appOutside>
        <div class="popupCloseButton">X</div>
        <p>Add any HTML content<br />inside the popup box!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

That change alone should work.

[Here is a fork with the change I made](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ef514?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: it is not woring `pop up is not closed`

Comment: It is working fine. You just don't forget to add event.stopPropagation() on trigger click